# Why is my c# code making going left and right much faster than forward and backwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to code some custom controls for some reason and for some reason going left and right is 100 times faster than going forwards and backwards. I've spent forever trying to fix it. I'm getting pretty mad and tired trying to fix it so please help me.

```
    void Start()
    {
        xVelocity = 0f;
        yVelocity = 0f;
        zVelocity = 0f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        yVelocity--;
        Control();
        transform.position += transform.up * Time.deltaTime * yVelocity;
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * zVelocity;
        transform.position += transform.TransformVector(-90, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * xVelocity;
    }

    private void Control()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            zVelocity += speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            zVelocity += -speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            xVelocity += speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            xVelocity += -speed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) == false && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == false)
        {

            if (zVelocity == 0 == false)
            {
                if (zVelocity < 0)
                {
                    zVelocity += friction;
                }
                else
                {
                    zVelocity -= friction;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) == false && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == false)
        {
            if (xVelocity == 0 == false)
            {
                if (xVelocity < 0)
                {
                    xVelocity += friction;
                }
                else
                {
                    xVelocity -= friction;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but: `if (zVelocity == 0 == false)` - is this not `if (zVelocity != 0)` ?

Comment: Not related to your problem per se, but some hints: `zVelocity == 0 == false` is the same as `zVelocity != 0`. Also, in a real environment, friction hinders movement whether or not any acceleration is being applied. I.e. in your code, you should always apply friction, not just when the keys are not held down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to code some custom controls for some reason and for some reason going left and right is 100 times faster than going forwards and backwards

Without a complete code example, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is. But…

I'll bet that it's not 100X, but rather 90X.

The `up` and `forward` vectors are unit vectors, i.e. magnitude of 1. But you are transforming your position along the X direction with an explicitly-constructed vector that has a magnitude of 90 (`transform.TransformVector(-90, 0, 0)`). So your left/right movement is 90X the magnitude of forward/back and up/down.

You should able to change the code to `transform.TransformVector(-1, 0, 0)` (a unit vector) and get the behavior you want.